# How to fetch data from Server Side using Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Normally React JS Using useEffect for Client Side Data Fetching but I want to fetch Data in server side in Next Js that time the code also reusable any one can clear my doubt

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyPageComponent({ data }) {
  // You page component that will be displayed on frontend
  // Here you can use useEffects that will be executed on the frontend as the page loads
}

// This gets called on every request on the BackendOnly!
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Do your server logic here, like fetching some api to get an initial state
  const res = await fetch(`site url`)
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to your page component via props
  // This will be accessible on the frontend
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default MyPageComponent
```

Comment: When Page Load Data Fetching use getInitialProps or getServerSideProps

Comment: this is the link actually i didn't understood please go through and explain it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321263/nextjs-app-ssg-getinitialprops-vs-getstaticprops-and-how-am-i-supposed-to-st

Comment: this code put _app.js or index.js file from pages directory